# Add text around the X label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Fig 1 is generated by Matlab, and the following code is created using Matlab `matlab2tikz` package. The different between Fig. 1 and Fig.2 is the position of `%` symbol. Fig.2 is produced by the converted code from Fig 1 using `matlab2tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\begin{document}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{1,0,1}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0,0.498039215803146,0}
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.600000023841858,0.200000002980232,0}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.52083333333333in,
height=3.565625in,
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=7,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.8pt,
mark=square*,
mark options={solid,fill=black},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.0596188675796392\\
2 0.167927145682257\\
3 0.471088374541939\\
4 0.500471624154843\\
5 0.681971904149063\\
6 0.712694471678914\\
7 0.978680649641159\\
};
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=4.0pt,
mark=*,
mark options={solid,fill=red},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.0424311375007417\\
2 0.0714454646006424\\
3 0.096730025780867\\
4 0.521649842464284\\
5 0.722439592366842\\
6 0.817547092079286\\
7 0.818148553859625\\
};
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,fill=blue},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.149865442477967\\
2 0.453797708726919\\
3 0.518594942510538\\
4 0.648991492712356\\
5 0.659605252908307\\
6 0.800330575352401\\
7 0.972974554763863\\
};
\addplot [
color=mycolor1,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,,rotate=180,fill=mycolor1},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.083469814858914\\
2 0.133171007607162\\
3 0.173388613119006\\
4 0.390937802323736\\
5 0.432391503783462\\
6 0.825313795402046\\
7 0.83137974283907\\
};
\addplot [
color=mycolor2,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,,rotate=270,fill=mycolor2},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.0604711791698936\\
2 0.399257770613576\\
3 0.416799467930787\\
4 0.526875830508296\\
5 0.627973359190104\\
6 0.656859890973707\\
7 0.80336439160244\\
};
\addplot [
color=mycolor3,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,,rotate=90,fill=mycolor3},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.015487125636019\\
2 0.106216344928664\\
3 0.167168409914656\\
4 0.291984079961715\\
5 0.372409740055537\\
6 0.43165117024872\\
7 0.984063724379154\\
};
\node[right, inner sep=0mm, text=black] at (axis cs:6.7, 0.05) {(\%)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%


\end{document}
```

I want to place the `%` symbol in Fig.2 like in Fig.1. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

[image: Fig.1]

[image: Fig.2]

Comment: Do you want it to be positioned exactly like in the Matlab screenshot, so slightly higher than the numbers? (It looks a bit off to me)

Comment: @Jake I want to place % on right of and at the same high of X label  "7", which means the x value are % scale. I tried many times to adjust the position values in (axis cs:6.7, 0.05), but all failed. It seams that % can only be placed in the plot screen.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you need to move the `\node` outside the `axis` environment (or set `clip=false` in the axis options, but that can produce undesired side effects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to add the `%` as an `xlabel`, and change the position of this, by adding

```
xlabel={(\%)},
xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1.01,0)},anchor=west}
```

to the `axis` options. `rel axis cs` is a coordinate system that is relative to the axes, with (0,0) in the lower left corner, and (1,1) in the upper right.

To shift the label down a bit, you can change the anchor to `north west`, as in Jake's answer, or add `yshift=<negative length>` to the `xlabel style`, i.e. `xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1.01,0)},anchor=north west}` or `xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1.01,0)},anchor=west,yshift=-1.5ex}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{1,0,1}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0,0.498039215803146,0}
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.600000023841858,0.200000002980232,0}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.52083333333333in,
height=3.565625in,
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=7,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
xlabel={(\%)},
xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1.01,0)},anchor=west}
]
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.8pt,
mark=square*,
mark options={solid,fill=black},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.0596188675796392\\
2 0.167927145682257\\
3 0.471088374541939\\
4 0.500471624154843\\
5 0.681971904149063\\
6 0.712694471678914\\
7 0.978680649641159\\
};
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=4.0pt,
mark=*,
mark options={solid,fill=red},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.0424311375007417\\
2 0.0714454646006424\\
3 0.096730025780867\\
4 0.521649842464284\\
5 0.722439592366842\\
6 0.817547092079286\\
7 0.818148553859625\\
};
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,fill=blue},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.149865442477967\\
2 0.453797708726919\\
3 0.518594942510538\\
4 0.648991492712356\\
5 0.659605252908307\\
6 0.800330575352401\\
7 0.972974554763863\\
};
\addplot [
color=mycolor1,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,,rotate=180,fill=mycolor1},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.083469814858914\\
2 0.133171007607162\\
3 0.173388613119006\\
4 0.390937802323736\\
5 0.432391503783462\\
6 0.825313795402046\\
7 0.83137974283907\\
};
\addplot [
color=mycolor2,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,,rotate=270,fill=mycolor2},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.0604711791698936\\
2 0.399257770613576\\
3 0.416799467930787\\
4 0.526875830508296\\
5 0.627973359190104\\
6 0.656859890973707\\
7 0.80336439160244\\
};
\addplot [
color=mycolor3,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,,rotate=90,fill=mycolor3},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.015487125636019\\
2 0.106216344928664\\
3 0.167168409914656\\
4 0.291984079961715\\
5 0.372409740055537\\
6 0.43165117024872\\
7 0.984063724379154\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Awesome. These different solutions greatly enrich my mind. Thanks all

Answer (score 4):

You can place the node by using `\node[anchor=north west, text height=1.5ex, xshift=0.5em] at (rel axis cs:1,0) {(\%)};` *outside the `axis` environment* (otherwise the label will be clipped off), or by putting

```
xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex},
after end axis/.code={
    \node[anchor=north west, text height=1.5ex, xshift=0.5em] at (rel axis cs:1,0) {(\%)};
}
```

(the code given in `after end axis/.code` is not clipped).

Note that you have to specify the `text height` for both the new node and for the existing tick labels, otherwise the alignment will be off (due to the parentheses, which have a greater height than the number).

The anchor `current axis.right of origin` refers to the tip of the x axis line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{1,0,1}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0,0.498039215803146,0}
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.600000023841858,0.200000002980232,0}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.52083333333333in,
height=3.565625in,
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=7,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex},
after end axis/.code={
    \node[anchor=north west, text height=1.5ex, xshift=0.5em] at (rel axis cs:1,0) {(\%)};
}
]
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.8pt,
mark=square*,
mark options={solid,fill=black},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.0596188675796392\\
2 0.167927145682257\\
3 0.471088374541939\\
4 0.500471624154843\\
5 0.681971904149063\\
6 0.712694471678914\\
7 0.978680649641159\\
};
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=4.0pt,
mark=*,
mark options={solid,fill=red},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.0424311375007417\\
2 0.0714454646006424\\
3 0.096730025780867\\
4 0.521649842464284\\
5 0.722439592366842\\
6 0.817547092079286\\
7 0.818148553859625\\
};
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,fill=blue},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.149865442477967\\
2 0.453797708726919\\
3 0.518594942510538\\
4 0.648991492712356\\
5 0.659605252908307\\
6 0.800330575352401\\
7 0.972974554763863\\
};
\addplot [
color=mycolor1,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,,rotate=180,fill=mycolor1},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.083469814858914\\
2 0.133171007607162\\
3 0.173388613119006\\
4 0.390937802323736\\
5 0.432391503783462\\
6 0.825313795402046\\
7 0.83137974283907\\
};
\addplot [
color=mycolor2,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,,rotate=270,fill=mycolor2},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.0604711791698936\\
2 0.399257770613576\\
3 0.416799467930787\\
4 0.526875830508296\\
5 0.627973359190104\\
6 0.656859890973707\\
7 0.80336439160244\\
};
\addplot [
color=mycolor3,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,,rotate=90,fill=mycolor3},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.015487125636019\\
2 0.106216344928664\\
3 0.167168409914656\\
4 0.291984079961715\\
5 0.372409740055537\\
6 0.43165117024872\\
7 0.984063724379154\\
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: Not what OP wants but I think that should be rendered as the `x axis scale`.

Comment: @percusse: Yeah, good point. Or probably even better as part of the axis label ("Saturation / %", or something like that).

Comment: @Jake Thanks for your reply! However, the % symbol is at the same high of x axis (——line), not the the same high of x label (like 1, 1.5,...,7). Can you move the % symbol a little bit lower. Thanks.

Comment: @percusse Can you modify my example using your concept? I am a newbie in compiling Tex code. Thanks!

Comment: @Jake I confronted with another problem when using your first version.  when I set the ymin=-0.1, ymax=1, and still used \node[right, text=black] at (current axis.right of origin) {(\%)}, the % symbol display unlike when setting ymin=0,ymax=1. It seams that it did not work out for the negative value of ymin in this example. Why?

Comment: @user22986: Yeah, sorry, what I said about the `right of origin` anchor wasn't accurate: It refers to a point to the right of the axis origin (0,0), so when your axis line is at a different y coordinate, the label doesn't align anymore. In that case you should use the `rel axis cs:1,0` approach. However, when you use `axis lines=middle`, the axis lines will go through the origin, and then you should use the `right of origin` approach.